# How to simplify this scientific notation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

How to find the answer of the following question
I missed the class in which it was taught how to solve this equation so step by step solution will be appreciated.
Thanks

$$\large \frac{(9 \cdot 10^{9}) (1.6 \cdot 10^{-19})^{2}}{(6.7 \cdot 10^{-11})(9.1 \cdot 10^{-31})(1.7 \cdot 10^{-27})}$$

Comment: There is no equation. Do you want us to evaluate the term? I can't parse the term, is everything after the ”/” in the denominator?

Comment: is it supposed to be $9x10^9$ or $9 \cdot 10^9$?

Comment: @Bob I really think those $x$es are $\times$es, here, denoting multiplication. This just isn't an equation. Even it was an $x$, it doesn't matter because they cancel each other out: three in the nominator, three in the denominator.

Comment: @K.Stm. Well judging on his topic title, I think TS just wants to simplify the fraction. Probably calls it an equation because he/she doesnt know how to call this.

Answer (score 1):

Hint 1:
$$\frac{x^n}{x^2}=x^{n-2}$$ $$x^n \cdot x^2=x^{n+2}$$

Hint 2:
All coefficients in denominator can be multiplied (same for numerator)